# Is there any review workflow API in BIM 360?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I need to automate workflow creation in projects and query document approval status, are there any plans for a BIM 360 Review and approval workflow API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review API - we don't have it, yet. But highly demanded feature.

Here is a wish ID:

ACSD-11159 (was ALEX-37150): “API wish: expose Docs Review API”  (cf. ACSFR-470: “Review API Release”)

also on Idea Station:
https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/bim-360-ideas/api-for-exposing-review-workflow-status/idi-p/9516122

You see quite a few requests. The product team is aware that this is high demands and put it as roadmap. You may want to join the vote there.

Comment: FYI - I added the link to this post to the above wish.  If you want to send us a business case, feel free to send it through forge.help@autodesk.com, pointing to this post.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I look forward to this feature being available soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can access reviews with a 3-legged token. The API is not documented, but the site acc.autodesk.com, uses it.

**get reviews**

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/dm/v2/projects/<project_id>?sort=-sequenceId&offset=0&limit=20
```

**get review info**

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/dm/v2/projects/<project_id>/reviews/<review_id>/versions?limit=50&offset=0
```

You can find a beta implementation in Python here: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-sdk-python/blob/a5987c7ffe60bdcf1472caeb1e6f268fd0a5a36d/src/autodesk_forge_sdk/reviews.py#L58-L98