# Autodesk Platform Services - how to get reviews that are related to a documents

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-construction-cloud

How can I get reviews that are related to a document?

It is possible to get relations between issues and documents using the [relationships endpoint](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/relationship-service-v2-get-relationship-by-id-GET/) (using a container ID), but I cannot find any method to show related reviews.

I searched the APS documentation without finding an answer:
https://aps.autodesk.com/developer/documentation

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Review API isn't exposed.
Please, refer to [known issues and wishes](https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2019/06/15/bim-360-acc-api-known-issues-and-wishes/) at Docs ACSD-11159

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that i posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74891063/8218981

You can access reviews with a 3-legged token. The API is not documented, but the site acc.autodesk.com, uses it.

**get reviews**

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/dm/v2/projects/<project_id>?sort=-sequenceId&offset=0&limit=20
```

**get review info**

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/dm/v2/projects/<project_id>/reviews/<review_id>/versions?limit=50&offset=0
```

You can find a beta implementation in Python here: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-sdk-python/blob/a5987c7ffe60bdcf1472caeb1e6f268fd0a5a36d/src/autodesk_forge_sdk/reviews.py#L58-L98