# Autodesk Forge / Platform Services: Get Reviews from Autodesk Construction Cloud

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-construction-cloud

I am trying to get review data from Autodesk construction cloud using autodesk Forge. There is no official review API but i found this post:

[Autodesk Platform Services - how to get reviews that are related to a documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74799417/autodesk-platform-services-how-to-get-reviews-that-are-related-to-a-documents)

Unfortunately my app is a server side app with 2 legged token so this does not work. Is there any other way to do this? I want to find who has approved a document. Is the Review API coming in the future? When?

Comment: It was accepted(https://autodesk.slack.com/archives/C12EGMUK0/p1679551099797389)
unfortunately we cannot give dates. The team is working on it, will let you know in case we get the date.

Comment: Please check if this is useful in your case https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-custom-attribute-definitions-GET/